# Populating Combobox Error 381

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

I am using the code below to populate a combobox 'cbQOper3' based on the value selected in combobox 'cbQOper2'. When I change the value selected in 'cbQOper2' I receive the following error message. If I check the list of values able in 'cbQOper3' they are the appropriate according the value selected in 'cbQOper2'

> Error number is : 381 Could not get the column property

```
Private Sub cbQOper2_Change()

Dim rngType As Range
Dim rngList As Range
Dim strSelected As String
Dim LastRow As Long

On Error GoTo errHandler:

'   Populate cbQOper3 based on value selected in tbQOper2
With Me.cbQOper3
    .Clear
    .ColumnCount = 2
    .ColumnWidths = "0;50"
    .BoundColumn = 2
End With

'   Check if Operation type has been select
    If cbQOper2.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        strSelected = cbQOper2.Value
        LastRow = Sheet11.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngList = Sheet11.Range("B6:B" & LastRow)
        For Each rngType In rngList
            If rngType.Value = strSelected Then
                cbQOper3.AddItem rngType.Offset(0, -1)
                cbQOper3.List(tbQOper3.ListCount - 1, 1) = rngType.Offset(0, 1)
            End If
        Next rngType
    End If

'   Error handler
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub

errHandler::
    MsgBox "An Error has Occured " & vbCrLf & "The error number is : " _
    & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & _
    "Please notify the administrator"

End Sub
```

Comment: `cbQOper3.List(tbQOper3.ListCount - 1, 1)` has an issue the ListCount is of a different object than you are applying to.

Comment: Thanks bulbus. Could you explain in more detail your comment ListCount is of a different object than you are applying to

Comment: What if `cbQOper3` is a list of 5 and `tbQOper3` is a list of 25??

Comment: I recommend to use human-readable names for your controls. I use `Cbx` for comboboxes and `Tbx` for textboxes, both of which I capitalise. I avoid having consecutive capitalise letters in any name. With these rules applied you would be looking at the difference between `CbxOper3` and TbxOper3` or, if you must have a Q, then `CbqOper3` and `TbqOper3`.